Is it possible to create your own timezone file?
With the command "sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata" is it possible to change the used timezone.
The choice is from the files in the directory /usr/share/timezone/Etc.
This directory contains files like GMT, GMT+1, GMT-1, UTC etc.
But it don't contain the timezone files UTC+1, UTC+2.
The timezone files are small and binary.
With xxd GMT+1 is it possible to see the content.
Is it possible to create your own UTC+1 timezone file?

it should be there under "Etc". It has been since well before 14.04 ;) sudo timedatectl set-timezone UTC does that work? it would switch to using UTC.  There is also timedatectl set-timezone UTC and timedatectl status to list it  It is better to use names ;)

A complete description of the timezone files can be found using man tzfile, and the official specification in RFC 8536.

Etc contains GMT GMT+1 GMT-1 UTC etc but not UTC-1
It was possible to create a UTC-1 file en copy it to /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc
But the commands "timedatectl list-timezones" and "dpkg-reconfigure tzdata" don't know that new timezone file.
